# Store JWT Token in closure

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jwt, vuex

I have heard that JWT tokens are recommended to be stored as follows:

- `access_token` in the application memory (as an example I was given - closures)
- `refresh_token` in cookie entries (HttpOnly)

At the moment, my `access_token` is stored in **localStorage** and is taken to check the authorization status:

`isLoggedIn: state => !!state.token`
in Vuex

`refresh_token` is stored in cookies.

I want to get away from this. I 'm wondering how to still store **access_token** in the **closure** ?

Comment: What is the point of storing the token in closure? Won't it be lost when you refresh the page?

Comment: @HarunYilmaz  localStorage is not secure, http Only cookies are impossible, because JS does not have access to them, then where to store it?

Comment: None, let the user re-login every time they refresh the page. Are you ok with that? most people not. Yes the `localStorage` is not absolute secure but also same as cookie. You have to trade-off between security and convenience. Read [LocalStorage vs Cookies](https://dev.to/cotter/localstorage-vs-cookies-all-you-need-to-know-about-storing-jwt-tokens-securely-in-the-front-end-15id)

Comment: What you have heard is correct. Never store tokens in local storage since it can be accessed easily using javascript. You can store the access token in memory and refresh token in httpOnly cookie. However, since you cannot read httpOnly Cookie from javascript, you need to use the refresh_token cookie to fetch the access token and user details using a API on every page reload and then store access token in memory and user details in localstorage.

Comment: @Ashwin Valento It turns out that I get access_token and save it in Vuex and every time the page is refreshed using refresh_token (which is recorded in a cookie) - I get user information and a new access_token and update it in state ?

Answer (score 0):

Keeping the token in a closure will depend on the exact implementation that you use and is a bit hard to demonstrate without any example code. Maybe you could post parts of the code where you're getting the access token and where you're using the access token?

To store the token in the memory, it doesn't have to be a closure, though. You can even keep it in vue's state - if you don't use any plugins which persist the state in local storage.

If you want to keep all of your tokens in a http-only cookie, you can achieve it by adding a lightweight backend component, which will handle the tokens for you. It adds a bit of complexity to your app, but increases security. It's what we call at Curity the Token Handler Pattern: https://curity.io/resources/learn/the-token-handler-pattern/

Comment: It turns out that I get access_token and save it in Vuex and every time the page is refreshed using refresh_token (which is recorded in a cookie) - I get user information and a new access_token and update it in state ?

Comment: Yes, that is a viable way of doing it.